# Как перевести выражение IsPostBack, в контекстве IsPostBack запрос ASP

Tags: asp.net

Это запрос который посылается от уже загруженой страничке при нажатии на кнопку или других действиях с контролами. Но почему же он называется IsPostBack запрос? Это же просто отправка "почты" на сервер. За что отвечает слово Back в названии? Или тут другой смысл в слове post, а именно - "после". И тогда это после возврата, может после возврата странички? Этот пазл никак не хочет вставляться в моем тетрисе )

Answer (score 1):

Почта - это mail. А Post, в данном контексте - это "отправка".

IsPostBack - является ли [текущий запрос] отправкой [данных с ранее отображенной страницы] обратно [на сервер].

Если True - текущий запрос вызван каким-то событием на странице, которую отобразили ранее (нажатием кнопки, сменой значения в комбике).
Если False - текущий запрос вызван первоначальным заходом пользователя на страинцу.

Comment: Спасибо, прояснили.